# Distance between Postcodes

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp-classic, location, postal-code

I am trying to find out the best way of working out distance between locations (we have the postcode and locations).

Basically with each record we have a Location and Postcode, the user on the front-end can enter a postcode and select records ..

```
- Within 10 Miles
- Within 20 Miles
- Within 40 Miles
- Within 50 Miles
```

The only way I can see doing this is by getting EACH record from the database and working out the distance between each, entering it into a temporary table and then ordering this table by location and filtering it. This seems like a long-winded and time-consuming way of doing it - does anyone have any suggestions of how this could be done better? Or is this the best way of doing it?

An example would be a customer enters SO40 9AA (Southampton Postcode) and then selects "within 50 miles", this should display and records within 50 miles of that postcode or location.

Comment: If you have access to longitude/latitude, gave a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117979/sql-server-geography-point and this http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=81360

Comment: which version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the geo-code in your dataset? 
If not you can add it for the zipcodes you have with a service like http://geocoder.us/help/city_state_zip.shtml
Or you can get a pre-coded database, available at http://www.zipinfo.com/products/z5ll/z5ll.htm
Once you add the code to the records, then you can use a standard mathematical distance calculation using the lat / long coordinates to calculate distance.

If you want driving distance, use the Google Maps API, otherwise this distance will be "as the crow flies."

Comment: These two solutions are great for US solutions, but that postcode by OP is UK.

Comment: Great point. Sorry. For UK addresses try this site http://www.freemaptools.com/download-uk-postcode-lat-lng.htm

Answer (score 0):

Once you the geo coords for all your postcodes, here's a VB function to get the strait distance between any two points. This produces results in miles, but easy enough to convert it.

```
Function distance(lat1 As Single, lon1 As Single, lat2 As Single, lon2 As Single)
  Dim theta As Single, dist As Single
  theta = deg2rad(lon1 - lon2)
  lat1 = deg2rad(lat1)
  lat2 = deg2rad(lat2)
  dist = Sin(lat1) * Sin(lat2) + Cos(lat1) * Cos(lat2) * Cos(theta)
  dist = acos(dist)
  dist = rad2deg(dist)
  distance = dist * 60 * 1.1515
End Function

'::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
':::  This function get the arccos function from arctan function    :::
'::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
Function acos(Rad)
  If Abs(Rad) <> 1 Then
    acos = pi / 2 - Atn(Rad / Sqr(1 - Rad * Rad))
  ElseIf Rad = -1 Then
    acos = pi
  End If
End Function


'::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
':::  This function converts decimal degrees to radians             :::
'::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
Function deg2rad(Deg As Single) As Single
    deg2rad = CSng(Deg * pi / 180)
End Function

'::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
':::  This function converts radians to decimal degrees             :::
'::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
Function rad2deg(Rad As Single) As Single
    rad2deg = CSng(Rad * 180 / pi)
End Function
```